# No module named 'ragas.langchain'

Tags: langchain

I get a error when run this import:

```
    from ragas.langchain import RagasEvaluatorChain
```

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 from ragas.langchain import RagasEvaluatorChain

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ragas.langchain'

I have the version 0.1.0 of RAGAS. I tried with other older versions but I get the same error.

Comment: I tried several methods and as well get the same error. However, this one > https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1C1Epju1lVkXTQi2jBq1njrOrmkfg0eQS > up to `print(test_df)` works for me, with using `from ragas.testset.generator import TestsetGenerator`

Answer (score 0):

According to this issue: https://github.com/explodinggradients/ragas/issues/571

ragas 0.1 does not support it yet:

> ragas 0.1 does not yet have this feature. We are working on it, for
> now you have two options
>
> Use ragas natively w/o the chain, in this way, you get all the new
> capabilities of 0.1 version reinstall and use 0.0.22

https://github.com/explodinggradients/ragas/issues/571#issuecomment-1932720980

You can downgrade it to ragas 0.0.11, just make sure to remove `context_precision` as it's not supported at this version

> I fixed it by installing ragas==0.0.11. LangChain article was written
> on August 23, 2023, while Ragas v0.0.11 was released the day after
> that.
>
> If you use v0.0.11 also make sure to remove context_precision as not
> yet supported back then.

https://github.com/explodinggradients/ragas/issues/571#issuecomment-1959008404

You can keep following that issue to check when this is going to be solved